# Typescript: How to use result of async task in Chain-ability of Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

I have the following typescript  function

```
    addSurgeryRequestPageOne(surgeryReservationModel: any): Promise<surgeryReservationModel> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.addSurgeryRequestUrl, JSON.stringify(  surgeryReservationModel ), { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().Data as surgeryReservationModel)
        //.then((res) => {
        //    item1 = res.SurgeryRequestId
        //}
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

As soon as this function gets executed I get surgeryRequestId back which I want to pass it in the below function.

```
 getSurgeryRequest(SurgeryRequestId: number): Promise<surgeryReservationModel> {
    return this.http.get(this.getSurgeryRequestUrl + '/' + SurgeryRequestId)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().Data as surgeryReservationModel)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

How do i go about this? I am new to typescript and its kind of hard to find resources. I am on ES5. not using ES6.

Comment: you actually **are** on ES6

Comment: @smnbbrv t in my tsconfig under compilerOptions property target says es5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best guess of what you are trying to do :

```
addSurgeryRequestPageOne(surgeryReservationModel: any): Promise<surgeryReservationModel> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.addSurgeryRequestUrl, JSON.stringify(  surgeryReservationModel ), { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().Data)
        .then(data => this.getSurgeryRequest(data.SurgeryRequestId))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```